# Unable to compile the smart contract using truffle compile command

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have created a project using truffle command. For that I am using below details in Myfile.sol and Migration.sol file:
pragma solidity 0.4.19

```
In truffle-config.js:
    development:{
      host:"127.0.0.1",
      port: 8585,
      network_id: "*",
    },
    compilers:{
      solc:{
          version: "0.4.19",
      }
    }

Issue: truffle compile  Could not find suitable configuration file  Truffle v5.0.11 (core: 5.0.11)  Node v11.6.0
```

Tried using truffle migrate but getting the same response.

Comment: can you rename file to  truffle.js and try again

Comment: Hi @Uahmed , I am able to run the truffle compile command . Looks like I have another issue which I have resolved now. Thanks for the suggestion.